# A matrix eigenvalue problem

Tags: matrices

In [my previous problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50967/an-eigenvalue-problem-for-positive-semidefinite-matrix), I made a typo. Now I restate it as a new problem.

Let  $  \begin{bmatrix}
A& B   \\ B^*  &C
\end{bmatrix}$ be positive semidefinite, $A,C$ are of size $n\times n$. Is it true that $$\quad \sum\limits_{i=1}^k\lambda_i\begin{bmatrix}
A& B   \\ B^*  &C
\end{bmatrix}\le \sum\limits_{i=1}^k\left(\lambda_i(A)+\lambda_i(C)\right)\quad, $$ 
where $1\le k\le n$? Here, $\lambda_i(\cdot)$ means the $i$th largest eigenvalue of $\cdot\quad$

Comment: I guess that $A$ and $C$ are Hermitian matrices. If this is the case, the [minmax theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) might help to prove the statement.

Comment: Yes, $A,C$ are Hermitian, but using minmax theorem I can proof the case $k=1$, and no more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered by T. Ito at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70689/ask-some-matrix-eigenvalue-inequalities

Answer (score 1):

It holds for $n = 1$. Solving the quadratic equation (with trace and determinant) for the largest eigenvalue of the lhs matrix, the desired inequality reads
$$ \frac{a+c+\sqrt{(a-c)^2 + 4|b|^2}}{2} \leq a + c.$$
Some algebra shows that (since $a+c \geq 0$) this is equivalent to
$$ |b|^2 \leq ac. $$
This follows (more or less) from Jacobi's criterion.